# Copying values into a byte array at a specific offset in a safe context

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, memcpy, unsafe

I am trying to copy the value of a uint into a byte array in C#. I have managed to accomplish this using code in an unsafe context but ideally, I would like to do this in a safe context

The code I am currently using is this

```
var bytes = new byte[] {0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}

fixed (byte* bytesPointer = bytes )
{
    *(ulong*)(bytesPointer + 1) = value;
}
```

The equivalent of what I am trying to accomplish in C# can be done like this in C++

```
unsigned char bytes[] = {0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}

memcpy(((unsigned long)bytes + 1), value, 4);
```

How could I do this in a safe context in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use these

[Array.Copy(Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

> Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the specified
>   source index and pastes them to another Array starting at the
>   specified destination index. The length and the indexes are specified
>   as 32-bit integers.

[Buffer.BlockCopy(Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Copies a specified number of bytes from a source array starting at a
>   particular offset to a destination array starting at a particular
>   offset.

Comment: The question is how to copy a `uint` (or, presumably, its `byte` representation) into a `byte[]`.  Can you demonstrate how these methods would be used to accomplish that?  The answer, as written, only makes mention of array-to-array copies; I think it would helpful to show that how to get a `byte[]` from a `uint` as well.

Comment: A `uint` is 4 unsigned bytes. To access the bytes in a uint, you can either mask and shift, or you can do the C# equivalent of a C `union`. That involves creating a `struct` using `LayoutKind.Explicit` that overlays the uint with 4 bytes. You set the uint part of the struct and then read the bytes.

Comment: @LostBoy are you sure this answered your question?

Comment: @Saruman When I saw the title I thought it was a "How do I copy between `byte` arrays?" question, too, and it took me a few reads to understand it.  I think you methods you listed can be used, you just need a call to [`BitConverter.GetBytes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_UInt32_) as an intermediate step.  I just thought that would make the answer more complete, is all.

Comment: Yeah as mentioned by @BACON I used BitConverter.GetBytes() to get the byte representation of the uint and then simply used Buffer.BlockCopy() to copy into the array

Comment: @LostBoy are ok, there other way to do it is use Flydog57 suggestion its probably a lot quicker, ill update the answer soon, im just at work in a phone meeting, trying to pretend im interested